# If PHP text file line equals, then do something

Tags: php, text, checkbox, flat-file

I am saving the state of a checkbox to a text file and reading it back in to show either a checked or non-checked box. The saving part is no problem - depending on whether I check or uncheck the box the value "Checked" or "Unchecked" is written to the text file. Echoing `echo $lines[0];` results in either value as expected. However, when using `if ($lines[0] == "Checked")` as shown in my code below, the value doesn't seem to be detected and therefore the echo that follows is not executed. What is the correct syntax for this situation?

```
      <?php
      $file = "textfile.txt";
      $lines = file($file); 
      ?>

      <input type="hidden" name="data1" value="Unchecked" />
      <input type="checkbox" name="data1" value="Checked" class="checkbox" 
        <?php
        if ($lines[0] == "Checked") {  
        echo 'checked="checked"';  
        }  
        ?>
      />
```

Comment: try to put echo into brackets ()

Comment: It may be due to black spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a line-break in your `$lines[0]` variable.

What you could do is:

```
if (trim($lines[0]) == "Checked") {
```

But what you should do, is switch to a database.

Comment: Or even better, use sessions. As saving the state of a checkbox is something you do, page to page, not something you save permanently into a file or database.

Comment: @Husman That would depend on the OP; a text file suggests a permanent save.

Comment: It's needed to turn on or off a feature in a mini CMS site. Unfortunately I don't have the experience to use a MySQL database but so far a flat file PHP database is working as I hoped. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Chris That kind of thing I would probably also save to a configuration file. You might want to look into for example http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php to see how you can easily retrieve key - value pairs from a file.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I will take a look. Also thank you for the answer - this solution is cleaner than the one below although both work well.

Answer (score 1):

The value can differ based on line endings.
I recommend you do the following:

```
if (stristr($lines[0], "unchecked")) {  
  echo '';  
}else{
  echo 'checked="checked"';  
}
```